# How do I get all user photos using the Google Photos API?

Tags: api, gdata, google-data-api, google-photos

I'm using the [Picasa Web Albums Data API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol) to access my Google Photos account. My goal is to download all photos between a given start and end time (old vacation pics). This API doesn't support server-side time filtering, so I'm trying to access the meta-data of the most recent 4000 images and filter them by time client-side. I have a working proof of concept, but I can only get the server to return ~900 image references (my Google Photos account easily has 40k total images). Is there some API method I am missing that lets me download the entire "feed" for my user so I can access meta-data on all my photos? Here is what I've tried...

```
# Tried this first, got ~900 results
pics = gd_client.GetUserFeed(kind='photo', limit=4000).entry
# Tried using the paging parameter start-index, but even if I 
# page through until it errors out, there are only ~900 results
pics = gd_client.GetFeed('/data/feed/api/user/default?kind=photo&max-results=100&start-index=500').entry
```

The APIs for albums do work correctly to list all images - the 'Auto Backup' album (that receives images from Google Photos on Android phones) has 30k images and I can query the meta data of them all.

Unfortunately I cannot put these images into one album and download them that way - user-created albums are limited to 2000 images. (I know there are around 3000 total images from this trip, because I can 'select' them in the web interface and see the total count, but you cannot download that many at once and you cannot add more than 2k to one album.)

Comment: question. Who do I use pagination with Picasa Photos? I searched and used the `start_index` but each time it did not get me new photos, its randomly getting data even duplicates. Any idea of how to correctly use pagination?

Comment: Nope. As far as I could tell, they don't really care to support this API. Please post if you find the answer!

Comment: I found the answer and posted it to benefit anyone wants the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got API to work as I'd desired, but I was able to "solve" this by downloading the target dates using [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout)

Answer (score 1):

After many tries, I think I got it to perfectly work.

What I did is playing with the `start-index` and `max-results` simultaneously.

You need to do it as follows (considering keeping `max-results` value same each request you hit):

1. `start-index` = 1 & `max-results` = **Any_Value_You_Want** ex: 50

Url request would look like:

```
/data/feed/api/user/default?kind=photo&max-results=50&start-index=1
```

2. `start-index` = 1 + previous `max-results` = 51 & `max-results` = 50

Url request would look like:

```
/data/feed/api/user/default?kind=photo&max-results=50&start-index=51
```

3. `start-index` = 51 + previous `max-results` = 101 & `max-results` = 50

Url request would look like:

```
/data/feed/api/user/default?kind=photo&max-results=50&start-index=101
```

And so on, each time you increase the `start-index` by its original value plus the `max-results` one in addition to maintaining 50 entries each url request, and it will perfectly work.